# Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization, determine zeros of the orthogonal functions.

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods

> **Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization theorem**
>
> The set of polynomials $\{ \phi_0(x), \phi_1(x), \ldots, \phi_n(x)\}$ in $[a,b]$ related to $w(x)$ as defined below is orthogonal:
>
> $$\begin{align}
> \phi_0(x) & = 1\\
> \phi_1(x) & = x-B_1\\
> \phi_k(x) &= (x-B_k)\phi_{k-1}(x) - C_k\phi_{k-2} (x)
> \end{align}$$
>
> (for certain calculated values of $B_i, C_i$)

After the proof I find a certain corollary.

> Consider:
>
> $$J_k = \begin{pmatrix}
> B_1 & \sqrt{C_2}& & \\
> \sqrt{C_2} & B_2 & \ddots & \\
> & \ddots & \ddots & \sqrt{C_k}\\
> & & \sqrt{C_k} & B_k
> \end{pmatrix}$$
>
> then the characteristic polynomial of $J_k$ is given by $\color{red}{(-1)^k} \phi_k(x)$. Calculating the zeros of $\phi_k(x)$ can be done by calculating the eigenvalues of a symmetric tridiagonal matrix.

Could someone explain how to derive the red part?

I tried the following:

Consider 
$$ \begin{pmatrix}
B_1 -x& \sqrt{C_2}& & \\
\sqrt{C_2} & B_2 -x& \ddots & \\
& \ddots & \ddots & \sqrt{C_k}\\
& & \sqrt{C_k} & B_k-x
\end{pmatrix}$$

Then $p_k(x) = (B_k-x) \cdot p_{k-1}(x) - \sqrt{C_k}\cdot \begin{vmatrix}
B_1 -x& \sqrt{C_2}& & \\
\sqrt{C_2} & B_2 -x& \ddots & \\
& \ddots & \ddots & \\
& & \sqrt{C_{k-1}} & \sqrt{C_k}
\end{vmatrix}$

Such that $p_k(x) = (B_k-x) \cdot p_{k-1}(x) - C_k p_{k-2}(x)$ and while this looks like $\phi_k(x)$ it's not exactly equal. How does one get there?

Comment: Some authors define the characteristic polynomial to be normalized;
$$\chi_A(\lambda) = \det(\lambda I - A)$$
Did you check if that works?

Comment: It's actually the other way round: From the definition of the $\phi_k$ one can find by induction that all $\phi_k$ are monic. The characteristic polynomial as referenced in the problem statement is therefore the $\det(A-\lambda I)$ variant.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you forgot about the sign of the permutation for Lagrange's theorem. If we adjust for that and also use the alternative definition of the characteristic polynomial, we get
$$p_k(\lambda) = \det(\lambda I_k - J_k) = (-1)^{k+1} (\lambda - B_k) p_{k-1} (\lambda) + (-1)^k (-1)^{k-1} C_k p_{k-2}(\lambda) = (-1)^{k+1} (\lambda-B_k) p_{k-1}(\lambda) - C_k p_{k-2}(\lambda)$$